# How to read next from my database sql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have an application of image loader, but what I want is to have a procedure for next and previous button so that I can view them one by one.

```
Private Sub Search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.Click
    Try
        disconnect()
        connect()

        cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select * FROM tblemployee WHERE lname ='" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()) & "' OR fname ='" & Trim(TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read() Then
            Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = dr("emp_pix")
            Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Information Record, Please Last Name only!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Please try again" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

## How can I manipulate for next and previous button?

```
Private Sub Next_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Next.Click
end sub

  'Do Here

 Private Sub Previous_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Previous.Click
end sub

  'Do Here
```

Comment: You would need to store the ID of the current record in a variable and then you can use that in your queries.  "Next" would be like `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE ID > @ID ORDER BY ID ASC` and "Previous" would be like `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE ID < @ID ORDER BY ID DESC`.  I'm not sure whether `TOP 1` works in MySQL but, if not, it may have something similar.  Even if it doesn't, you are using a data reader so you can simply read the first row and ignore the rest.

Comment: This was the first thing I got with Google...  http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/datagrid/article.php/c13153/Custom-DataGrid-With-Next-Previous-First-Last-and-Numeric-Paging.htm

Comment: Note that my SQL examples use parameters.  You should change your code to do so and ALWAYS do so.  You can read more about that here: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html.  I would also recommend that you download Connector/Net from MySQL and use that rather than ODBC, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: how can I get the next I have a column in my database 'date_hired' with format of 'YYYY-MM-DD' It would be help for my sorting

Comment: note that my loading of image is working, i just want to have a next button and prev button so that I can view them one by one